# Можно ли так сказать?

Tags: лексика, пунктуация

И нужна ли запятая:
"Исходя из изложенного выше(,) решения совета носят рекомендательный характер".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, так сказать нельзя. Лучше будет: "Исходя из изложенного выше, можно сказать, что решения совета..."

Answer (score 0):

В связи с изложенным выше решения совета носят рекомендательный характер