# Обособление оборота со словами "исходя из"

Tags: пунктуация

Исходя из содержания проекта закона(,) его реализация потребует выделения дополнительных средств.

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/440798/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81-%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 2):

Предложение некорректно составлено (см. [Можно ли так сказать?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/4858/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c))

Реализация не исходит из чего-то, это мы исходим из чего-то, делая наши выводы.

Верно: **Исходя из содержания проекта закона, можно заключить, что его реализация потребует выделения дополнительных средств.**

> Но оборот со словами *исходя из* обособляется, если относится к производителю действия, который может «исходить из чего-то» (определенное или неопределенное лицо): Калькулятор составил расчёт, исходя из представленных ему данных; Налогом облагают, исходя из установленных ставок, Лётчикам предоставляется право изменять свой боевой порядок, исходя из сложившейся обстановки.([ДЕЕПРИЧАСТНЫЕ КОНСТРУКЦИИ](http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=136#pp136))

Дополнение.
Последовавшее обсуждение показало, что зря я был так категоричен в вопросе о запятой. Здесь стоит безличное "можно", возможно, правило Розенталя в таком случае не действует. Поиск в Нацкорпусе дает 28:14. (Все-таки большинство авторов ставит запятую.) Вот противоположные примеры.

> **Исходя из этого, можно предположить** наличие очагов болезни также и в благополучных по данным серологического анализа стадах. [Использование диагностических ДНК-зондов для обнаружения провируса вируса бычьего лейкоза у инфицированных животных (2002) // «Вопросы вирусологии», 2002.12.02]
>
> **Исходя из этого можно объяснить** и карточную символику Пушкина. [Феликс Раскольников. Статьи о русской литературе (1986-2000)]

Comment: _Верно: **Исходя из содержания проекта закона, можно заключить...**_ — Это не верно. Запятая здесь не нужна, поскольку нет производителя действия. О.Д. Фрамполь в своём словаре приводит в качестве примера ошибку М.Горького в следующем предложении: **Исходя из этого факта, следует пизнатъ, что трепки он стоит...** (М.Горький). О.Д. Фрамполь подчёркивает, что запятая не нужна. Не вижу существенной разницы между "можно заключить" и "следует признать".

Comment: @grizzly У Розенталя находим другое мнение (см. мой ответ). Нам придется решать дело в Верховном суде :)

Comment: Вы посмотрите внимательнее правило Розенталя. В этом случае они с Фрамполь не противоречат друг другу. Розенталь тоже говорит, что обычно этот оборот не обособляется. Рассматриваемый случай относится к этому "обычно", а не к процитированному в ответе исключению.

Comment: У Розенталя: Лётчикам предоставляется право изменять свой боевой порядок, исходя из сложившейся обстановки. В чем разница между "предоставляется право" и  "можно заключить"?

Comment: Здесь "лётчики" — производители действия, они изменяют порядок, исходя из... А Вы трактуете это предложение так, будто им "предоставляется право исходя из".

Comment: @grizzly Хотелось бы разобраться до конца. По-вашему "исходя из этого факта **можно** заключить" - нет производителя действия и запятая не нужна , а "исходя из этого факта, **можем** заключить" — есть производитель действия и запятая нужна?

Comment: Да, я думаю, что именно так следует понимать правило Розенталя. И ещё я думаю, что это наиболее сложный вариант различия (не указано явно действующее лицо). Фрамполь этот случай вообще не рассматривает.

Comment: Возможно, формально Вы правы. Но как-то не согласуется со здравым смыслом. Однако мою уверенность Вы разрушили :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78139/discussion-between-grizzly-and--).

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что запятая не нужна:

**Исходя из содержания проекта закона можно заключить, что его реализация потребует выделения дополнительных средств.**

Предлог ИСХОДЯ можно убрать: **Из содержания проекта закона можно заключить, что его реализация потребует выделения дополнительных средств.** Паузы там нет, предложение составляет одну фразу.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

"**Конечно, здесь производитель действия явно назван, поэтому не должно быть споров по поводу запятой**". Да, утверждение весьма категоричное, и тема это – хороший повод для того, чтобы вспомнить **назначение знаков препинания.**

Так вот, знаки препинания нужны для того, чтобы **прояснить структуру предложения,** быстро и правильно прочитать его и  понять смысл, при этом "производитель действия"  для читателя совсем не на первом месте. Что касается нашего случая, то этот самый "производитель" привел  нас к неверному решению.

Почему? Дело в том, что конструкция этого (редактированного) предложения **явно двухчастная:** Исходя из содержания проекта закона можно заключить,// что его реализация потребует выделения дополнительных средств. Его можно записать совсем просто: **Из проекта закона можно заключить,// что его реализация потребует выделения дополнительных средств**.

А если поставить эту "бесспорную" запятую, то она  делит наше предложение **на три части,** и таким образом мы получаем **вставочную конструкцию**, которая обычно выделяется двумя паузами и читается с понижением тона. Но это же совсем не наш случай, и запятая, по поводу которой не должно быть споров, не проясняет содержание, а скорее затемняет его.

Все дело в том, что правило Розенталя (как, впрочем, и все правила) – это решение конкретной задачи, и эта задача решалась для простого, а не сложного  предложения.

Но и с учетом правила в нашем  случае мы имеем **пассивную  конструкцию** без явного производителя действия, а вот ее активный вариант использовать не надо (**можно** сделать заключение // **мы можем** сделать заключение). Поэтому ИСХОДЯ ИЗ – это **производный предлог** на основе деепричастия, а не само деепричастие, и мы имеем право **запятую не ставить.**

Comment: Jasmin, то, что Вы цитируете ("Конечно, здесь производитель действия явно назван, поэтому не должно быть споров по поводу запятой") я писал о варианте с активной конструкцией ("мы можем")

Comment: Здесь нежелательно использовать активную конструкцию, чтобы не нарушать правила Розенталя. И зачем вообще усложнять предложение, если это никак не меняет его содержание? А ответ Ваш  я цитировала  в связи с оценкой "бесспорно".  Мне кажется, что всё "бесспорное" ограничивает наше мышление и мешает найти оптимальное решение.

Answer (score 0):

> Исходя из содержания проекта закона, мы считаем, что его реализация
>   потребует выделения дополнительных средств.

Похоже, все согласны, что предложение лучше перефразировать. В предложенном варианте действие деепричастного оборота (который отделён *запятой*) и глагола привязаны к общему производителю действия.

Comment: Конечно, здесь производитель действия явно назван, поэтому не должно быть споров по поводу запятой. Но устроит ли автора это "мы"?

Comment: Здесь нужно определиться, кто именно "исходит", мы (меньшее из зол), неизвестно кто или "реализация" (как в исходном варианте). В других предложенных вариантах запятая, на мой взгляд, тоже нужна.

Comment: Похоже на статью для газеты. В таких статьях обычно не пишут "мы считаем". Скорее всего, имеется в виду нечто объективное (проект закона таков, что его реализация  потребует выделения дополнительных средств). Реализация не может "исходить", остается что-то безличное.

Comment: Для меня это похоже на доклад авторов закона или на выступление с его обсуждением. Если говорящий не считает нужным оговориться, что высказывает _своё_ мнение, то ему не нужно и слово "исходя". У меня такое ощущение, что Розенталь, приведя альтернативный ворох газетных канцеляризмов (а-ля реализация исходит), попытался их спасти, приравняв сочетание "исходя из" выражению "на основании" - тогда можно объявить "исходя" другой частью речи, отбросить и т. п.

Comment: О производителях действия: они не обязаны быть выражены грамматически (предложение может быть _неопределённо-личным_). Важно, чтобы действия деепричастия и глагола на них сходились. Пример с запятой и предикативом "надо" (из того же ряда, что **можно**) из академического издания "Русская грамматика" (ред. Шведовой и др., 1980). Обстоятельственно-характеризующие значения деепричастия могут быть различны... Условное значение: _Претендуя на эту должность, **надо** обладать талантом организатора..._